Question about lifting of a function
Theorem 1
Suppose that $p : X \to Y$ is a covering map. Suppose $\gamma_0, \gamma_1 : [0, 1] \to Y$ are continuous, $x_0 \in X$ and $p(x_0) = \gamma_0(0) = \gamma_1(0)$. Fie $\tilde{\gamma}_0$ and $\tilde{\gamma}_1$ be the continuous functions mapping [0,1] to X such that $\tilde{\gamma}_j(0) = x_0$ and $p \circ \tilde{\gamma}_j = \gamma_j$ for $j = 0, 1$. If $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ are path-homotopic then $\tilde{\gamma}_0(1) = \tilde{\gamma}_1(1)$.
 Theorem 2
Suppose that $p:X \to Y$ is a covering map, $D$ is a path-connected, locally path-connected and simply connected topological space and $f:D \to Y$ is continuous. Suppose that $a \in D$. Fix $x_0 \in X$ with $p(x_0) = f(a)$. There exists a unique continuous function $\tilde{f} : D \to X$ such that $f(a) = x_0$ and $p \circ \tilde{f} = f$.
I don't understand very well the proof of Theorem 2:

Given $b \in D$, let $\gamma:[0,1] \to D$ be continuous with $\gamma(0) = a$ and $\gamma(1) = b$. Let $\tilde{\gamma}$ be a lifting of $f \circ \gamma$ with $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = x_0$.

Ok. Until there I understand that he constructs the unique path-lifting.

Define $\tilde{f}(b) = \tilde{\gamma}(1)$. Since $D$ is simply connected, Theorem 1 shows that $f$ is well defined.

Here I don't understand anything. If you can help me to understand.. from where is that $\tilde{f}$ function already defined? Thanks!

You'll want to convince yourself that since D is simply connected, any two paths that start at $a$ and end at $b$ for fixed $b$ are path homotopic, and therefore so are the paths obtained by composing with f. The aim here is to convince yourself that the definition given for the lift of $f$ does not depend on the choice of path from $a$ to $b$.

@user176372 I still think for 2 hours but I don't know how to proceed. I think I understand what you want to say but can't write mathematically

Notice that the function $\tilde{f}:D\to X$ that the proof of Theorem 2 purports to construct seems like it may depend on the choice of path $\gamma:I\to D$ starting at $a$ and ending at $b$ used.
So, you want to convince yourself that if $\gamma_1,\gamma_2:I\to D$ are any two paths starting at $a$ and ending at $b$ with liftings $\tilde{\gamma_1},\tilde{\gamma_2}:I\to X$ of $f\circ\gamma_i$ for $i=1,2$ respectively, then $\tilde{\gamma_1}(1) = \tilde{\gamma_2}(1)$.
By Theorem 1, it's sufficient to prove that $f\circ\gamma_1\simeq f\circ\gamma_2$. It's subsequently enough to prove that $\gamma_1\simeq\gamma_2$.
Let $c_b:I\to D$ be the constant loop at $b\in D$. Then $\gamma_1\simeq \gamma_1\cdot c_b$ (this is a fact you should know). Also, $c_b \simeq \overline{\gamma_1}\cdot\gamma_2$ because $D$ is simply connected, i.e., the group $\pi_1(D,b)$ is trivial so that any loop based at $b$ is homotopy equivalent to the constant loop. So we have that $\gamma_1\simeq \gamma_1\cdot\overline{\gamma_1}\cdot\gamma_2\simeq c_a \cdot \gamma_2 \simeq \gamma_2$, where we've used associativity of the concatenation operation under homotopy equivalence a few times.

Ummm... I forgot to mention that I never took a Algebraic Topology class. This is from a Complex Analysis book, and I need this to proof Picard Theorem.

@MathLearner Well, good luck then. If whatever book you're reading doesn't have some kind of algebraic topology prerequisite, then it must have its own development of some sufficient cut through that gets you to this kind of result. I'd consider that idiosyncratic for a question tagged "algebraic topology" myself, and if you have idiosyncratic constraints on your question it's probably best to put those in your question body.
